# Vue js mutate arrray value

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Vue.js just won't let me change an array value:

```
<div class="col-sm-1 col-md-1" v-for="(l, i) in locations" :key="i">
     <span :class="{'location-active': isActive[1]}" @click="setActive">{{l}}</span>
</div>
```

Data:

```
   data() {
        return {
            isActive: [false, false, false, false, false]
        }
    }
```

Method:

```
  setActive() {
        this.isActive[1] = true;
    }
```

I was using for loops first and it didn't work, so tried to set the value of the array manually it just won't work, it just won't set isActive[index] to true.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a common "gotcha" with Vue and how it can find model changes.

https://vuejs.org/2016/02/06/common-gotchas/

> When you modify an Array by directly setting an index (e.g. arr[0] = val) or modifying its length property. Similarly, Vue.js cannot pickup these changes. Always modify arrays by using an Array instance method, or replacing it entirely. Vue provides a convenience method arr.$set(index, value) which is syntax sugar for arr.splice(index, 1, value).

Syntax was updated in 2.0 though to the following:

`Vue.set( target, propertyName/index, value )`

so in your case

`Vue.set(this.isActive, 1 ,true);`

Also see here: http://vuejs.org/guide/list.html#Array-Change-Detection

Comment: //this.isActive.$set(1, true); like that? it still doesn't work

Comment: thank you, it was very frustrating I spent hours fixing this simple problem. I didn't realize that it was a limitation from Vue

Comment: @StormAsdg yeah it's actually a limitation within javascript itself and how it can notify things of changes. Definitely wasted some time myself on an issue like this